# Iterate over and count objects inside objects inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to return a count of people who live in Valencia.

For example, the below arr would return a count of 2.

```
const arr = [
      { name: 'Cassandra', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 32.5 },
      { name: 'Cassandrella', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 35.55 }
    ]
```

I am having trouble accessing the objects and with looping over an object inside an object inside the array. This is the code I have gotten so far. I know I am going wrong somewhere but I can't seem to work it out.

```
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
  var count = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i = people.length; i++) {
     if (people[i].lives.city === 'Valencia') {
      count++;
     }
   }
   return count;                                 
}
```

Comment: Just change to `i < people.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a check as second parameter for `for` statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         check
```

```js
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people[i].lives.city === 'Valencia') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

const arr = [{ name: 'Cassandra', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 32.5 }, { name: 'Cassandrella', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 35.55 }];

console.log(countPeopleInValencia(arr));
```

Comment: `need` is a strong word :) `i < people.length` is acceptable without the second parameter. Might be worth mentioning that often the 2nd parameter is worth including because that way you can cache the length of the array so you don't have to keep checking it for each loop iteration.

Comment: @Andy It's hardly worth the additional code complexity, every modern compiler does it anyway

Comment: some say so some so some, what ever. now without caching the length.

Comment: Thank you for all of the advice guys. I was so close!

Answer (score 1):

```
function countPeopleInValencia(people) {
    return people.filter(p => p.lives.city === 'Valencia').length;
}

const arr = [
    { name: 'Cassandra', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 32.5 },
    { name: 'Cassandrella', lives: { country: 'Spain', city: 'Valencia' }, age: 35.55 }
]


console.log(countPeopleInValencia(arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

it can be one liner

```
arr.filter(function(o){return o.lives.city==="Valencia"}).length
```

or

```
$.map(arr,function(o){return o.lives.city==="Valencia"}).length
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! My next step after learning to for loop it was to try and figure out a higher order function method for this, this greatly helps :)